# Could the automat* tags be cleaned up?

Tags: discussion, tags, ambiguous-tags, automation

There are several tags:

- [automate](/questions/tagged/automate) 62 questions
- [automated](/questions/tagged/automated) 77 questions
- [automatic](/questions/tagged/automatic) 147 questions
- [automator](/questions/tagged/automator) 72 questions
- [automata](/questions/tagged/automata) 45 questions
- [automatically](/questions/tagged/automatically) 55 questions
- [automaton](/questions/tagged/automaton) 13 questions
- [automation](/questions/tagged/automation) 1,664 questions

And also these:

- [automagic](/questions/tagged/automagic) 8 questions
- [auto](/questions/tagged/auto) 226 questions

And this is not counting things like:

[build-automation](/questions/tagged/build-automation)  [webautomation](/questions/tagged/webautomation)  [autocomplete](/questions/tagged/autocomplete) [automake](/questions/tagged/automake) [autogenerate](/questions/tagged/autogenerate)  [ole-automation](/questions/tagged/ole-automation)  [word-automation](/questions/tagged/word-automation)  [office-automation](/questions/tagged/office-automation)  [ui-automation](/questions/tagged/ui-automation)  [gui-automation](/questions/tagged/gui-automation)  [wpf-automation](/questions/tagged/wpf-automation)  [wafflemate](/questions/tagged/wafflemate) etc...

I realize that there are several distinct topics, but could these be cleaned up somehow.  And perhaps a few permanently destroyed?

**Perhaps:**

- [gui-automation](/questions/tagged/gui-automation) -> [ui-automation](/questions/tagged/ui-automation)
- [automatically](/questions/tagged/automatically) -> [automatic](/questions/tagged/automatic)
- [automate](/questions/tagged/automate) -> [automatic](/questions/tagged/automatic)
- [automated](/questions/tagged/automated) -> [automatic](/questions/tagged/automatic)
- [automaton](/questions/tagged/automaton) -> [automata](/questions/tagged/automata)
- [automator](/questions/tagged/automator) be left alone?

**Burninate:**

- [automation](/questions/tagged/automation) in favor of about a million more specific **XX**-automation tags?

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't resist.  ;)

Comment: auto-burninate...

Comment: why would you burninate [automator]? It's the only one that's actually about a [product](http://www.apple.com/macosx/apps/all.html#automator)...

Comment: Because I'm not omniscient, like Jon Skeet, I'm not a mac user, and I didn't go through the last couple of tags.  Sorry 'bout that.  Updated.

Comment: @Brock or anyone, please feel free to edit.  Mark CW if you like.  I just included [tag:automaton] because I noticed a few questions tagged with it also had [tag:automata].

Comment: I deleted my comment because I saw that, and realized that there was room for cleanup there, too.  Edited the question accordingly.

Comment: @M. Tibbits sorry, my earlier comment was a bit snarkier than I meant it to be...

Comment: hehe.  No worries Jon.  I was running on a few hours of sleep, so my response was equally such.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I completed the suggestions in "Perhaps:", so that leaves

[automation](/questions/tagged/automation)

[automatic](/questions/tagged/automatic)

Comment: hmm, I missed [automagic] and [auto], those are merged now as well.